# How to check whether a representation $G\to\mathrm{GL}(n,\Bbb R)$ is irreducible?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I know there is a very beautiful theory for representations over $\Bbb C$, especially the [character theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_theory) makes it almost trivial to check whether a given representation $G\to\mathrm{GL}(n,\Bbb C)$ is irreducible.

But how can I check this in a similarly algorithmic fashion for representations over $\Bbb R$? I am specifically interested in the case of finite groups.

> **Question**: Given a finite group $G$ and a representation $\rho:G\to\mathrm{GL}(n,\Bbb R)$. How to determine (algorithmically) whether $\rho$ is irreducible?

---

**Note I**

I am aware of [Frobenius-Schur indicator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius%E2%80%93Schur_indicator) but I cannot understand whether and how it helps me for my question. At first, I do *not* have a representation over $\Bbb C$ to start with. And I am not really interested in transforming my irreducible representation over $\Bbb R$ into one or more irreducible representation over $\Bbb C$.

---

**Note II**

I avoid using the term "real representation" as it seems to have the meaning of a representation over $\Bbb C$ with a real valued character. I am not very familiar with the connection of this term and "representations over $\Bbb R$" that I use. But please enlighten me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818543/easy-way-to-get-real-irreducible-characters-reps-from-complex-irreducible-char

Comment: When a real irrep $V$ is complexified, precisely three things can happen, and these are classified by the [Frobenius-Schur indicator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius–Schur_indicator).

Comment: @Joppy I have a hard time grasping how these indicators work in "my direction". What I see is: they can classify irrep. representations over $\Bbb C$ into three classes. But what do they tell me when I start from a representation over $\Bbb R$ and what do they tell me about irreducibility?

Comment: @user10354138 The other question seems to be about deciding whether a given complex irreducible is equivalent to a real representation. Here we are given a real representation as input. Clearly if it is irreducible over ${\mathbb C}$ then it is irreducible over ${\mathbb R}$, and if it is the sum of more than two complex irreducibles then it is reducible over ${\mathbb R}$. The tricky case is where it is the sum of two complex irreducibles. In that case you would need to idenify them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the links in the comments below the question brought me to the following [website](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~jm/wiki/Representations/CharacterTheory), which contains a nice characterization of irreducible representations over $\Bbb R$:

> A representation $\rho:G\to\mathrm{GL}(n,\Bbb R)$ with character $\chi=\mathrm{tr}(\rho)$ is irreducible, if and only if
>   $$\|\chi\|^2+\nu(\chi)=2.$$

Here $\|\chi\|^2$ is the squared norm of the character, and $\nu$ is the [Frobenius-Schur indicator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius%E2%80%93Schur_indicator) defined by

$$\|\chi\|^2=\frac1{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi^2(g),\qquad \nu(\chi):=\frac1{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\chi(g^2).$$